# PySide6 - QTableWidget - Drag and Drop - CellWidget - lost anywhere --> Is something wrong with my question?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, qtablewidget, pyside6

I need to drag and drop (move) CellWidget in a QtableWidget.

I can move them, but if i drop a CellWidget on a cell occupied by an other one, i deleted the previous.
Example : (row, col)
B(0, 1) move to (1, 2)
C(0, 2) move to (0, 1)
B is deleted.

More : A cellWidget can't be put on an old position.

Here is my minimal code.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PySide6.QtGui import QDrag


class DragButton(QPushButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.nb_col = 5
        self.nb_row = 5
        self.tbl = QTableWidget(self.nb_row, self.nb_col)
        self.tbl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([str(x) for x in range(self.nb_col)])
        self.tbl.setVerticalHeaderLabels([str(x) for x in range(self.nb_row)])

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tbl)

        nom = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        for l in range(len(nom)):
            new_btn = DragButton(nom[l])
            new_btn2 = DragButton(nom[l] + 'j')
            self.tbl.setCellWidget(0, l, new_btn)
            self.tbl.setCellWidget(l, 1, new_btn2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.position()
        widget = e.source()
        row = self.tbl.rowAt(position.y() - self.tbl.horizontalHeader().height() - self.tbl.y())
        column = self.tbl.columnAt(position.x() - self.tbl.x())
        self.tbl.setCellWidget(row, column, widget)
        e.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

Thanks for your help.
Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be a little late to the party ^^ but I just had the same problem on a QTableWidget, the trick is to create a temporary QWidget and QHBoxLayout in which you place your buttons or whatever. That way, those temporary widgets will get destroyed instead.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QTableWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QMimeData
from PySide6.QtGui import QDrag


class DragButton(QPushButton):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QDrag(self)
            mime = QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            drag.exec(Qt.MoveAction)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.nb_col = 5
        self.nb_row = 5
        self.tbl = QTableWidget(self.nb_row, self.nb_col)
        self.tbl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([str(x) for x in range(self.nb_col)])
        self.tbl.setVerticalHeaderLabels([str(x) for x in range(self.nb_row)])

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tbl)

        nom = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        for l in range(len(nom)):
            new_btn = DragButton(nom[l])
            new_btn2 = DragButton(nom[l] + 'j')
            self.set_cell_widget(0, l, new_btn)
            self.set_cell_widget(l, 1, new_btn2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def set_cell_widget(self, row, column, widget):
        container_widget = QWidget()
        container_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        container_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        container_layout.setSpacing(0)
        container_widget.setLayout(container_layout)
        container_layout.addWidget(widget)

        self.tbl.setCellWidget(row, column, container_widget)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        position = e.position()
        widget = e.source()
        row = self.tbl.rowAt(position.y() - self.tbl.horizontalHeader().height() - self.tbl.y())
        column = self.tbl.columnAt(position.x() - self.tbl.x())
        self.set_cell_widget(row, column, widget)
        e.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    w.showMaximized()
    app.exec()
```

Hope this helps!